# How to automatically update and get a relation column based on other relation

Tags: typescript, postgresql, rxjs, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to connect 3 relations - Photo, PhotoComment and PhotoRating. I want to let my users to have a possibility to rate a photo. These photos can have multiple comments by many users and multiple rates by many users (but only 1 rate per specific user). And I want to show that user rate on all comments that belongs to photos. However, I cannot make things work to show a rate inside comment and update it automatically whenever user change photo rate (uses `ratePhoto` method)

When I call `ratePhoto` method I can see in PGAdmin that `photoRatingId` is not connected with `PhotoComment` and it's not updating rate there. However, `ratePhoto` method works fine and saves rate of `Photo` correctly

I'm using NestJS, TypeORM, PostgreSQL and RxJS. I highly prefer to work on repository instead of queryBuilder

`photos.service.ts`

```
public ratePhoto(photoId: number, ratePhotoDto: RatePhotoDto, user: User): Observable<any> {
        return this.getPhoto(photoId).pipe(
            switchMap((photo: Photo) => from(this.photoRatingRepository.findOneBy({ photo: { id: photo.id }, user: { id: user.id } })).pipe(
                map((photoRating: PhotoRating) => {
                    if (!photoRating) {
                        const newRating: PhotoRating = new PhotoRating();

                        newRating.rate = ratePhotoDto.rate;
                        newRating.user = user;
                        newRating.photo = photo;

                        return this.photoRatingRepository.save(newRating);
                    }

                    photoRating.rate = ratePhotoDto.rate;

                    return this.photoRatingRepository.save(photoRating);
                }),
            )),
        );
    }
```

`photo.entity.ts`

```
@Entity()
export class Photo {
    //...

    @OneToMany(() => PhotoComment, (photoComment: PhotoComment) => photoComment.photo)
    public photoComments: PhotoComment[];

    @OneToMany(() => PhotoRating, (photoRating: PhotoRating) => photoRating.photo)
    public photoRatings: PhotoRating[];
}
```

`photo-comment.entity.ts`

```
@Entity()
export class PhotoComment {
    //...

    @ManyToOne(() => Photo, (photo: Photo) => photo.photoComments, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    public photo: Photo;

    @ManyToOne(() => PhotoRating, (photoRating: PhotoRating) => photoRating.photoComment)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'rate' })
    public photoRating: PhotoRating;
}
```

`photo-rating.entity.ts`

```
@Entity()
@Unique(['user', 'photo'])
export class PhotoRating {
    //...
    
    @Transform(({ value }) => +value)
    @Column({ type: 'decimal', precision: 3, scale: 2, default: 0 })
    public rate: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => Photo, (photo: Photo) => photo.photoRatings, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    public photo: Photo;

    @OneToMany(() => PhotoComment, (photoComment: PhotoComment) => photoComment.photoRating, { cascade: true })
    public photoComment: PhotoComment;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why does `PhotoComment` entity has that `photoRating` property, and why does `PhotoRating` has that `photoComment`. Is it required to have a `photoRating` for a `photo` record or `photoComment` record?

Comment: I've set these entities with relations between themselves. Maybe I'm wrong, cause I'm still newbie in NestJS and TypeORM, however I think if I want to show a `rate` (which comes from `photoRating` in my comments (`PhotoComment` entity) and automatically adjust this rate on comments whenever user changes it (`ratePhoto` method on `Photo` entity), I have to set these relations. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. Most of the things were made correctly however because I wasn't updating PhotoComment Entity, my rate wasn't present on PhotoRating Entity. I didn't want to get all the comments and save it manually, however I forgot about `.update()` method. I also refactored my method to use `transaction` and instead of `RxJS` I switched to promises because unfortunately, RxJS here wasn't the best option. So my code now looks more or less like this:

`photos.service.ts`

```
public async ratePhoto(photoId: number, ratePhotoDto: RatePhotoDto, user: User): Promise<void> {
        await this.entityManager.transaction(async (entityManager: EntityManager) => {
            const photo: Photo = await this.photoRepository.findOne({ where: { photo: { id: photoId } } });
            const photoRating: PhotoRating = await this.photoRatingRepository.findOne({ where: { photo: { id: photo.id }, user: { id: user.id } } });
    
            if (!photoRating) {
                const newRating: PhotoRating = await entityManager.save( // Saving new rate of photo
                    PhotoRating, 
                    { ...ratePhotoDto, user, photo }
                );
    
                await entityManager.update( // Fast update all comments that should be updated
                    PhotoComment,
                    { addedBy: { id: user.id }, photo: { id: photo.id } },
                    { photoRating: newRating }
                );
    
                return;
            }
    
            await entityManager.save( // Saving rate of photo
                PhotoRating, 
                { ...photoRating, ...ratePhotoDto }
            );
    
            await entityManager.update( // Fast update all comments that should be updated
                PhotoComment,
                { addedBy: { id: user.id }, photo: { id: photo.id } },
                { photoRating }
            );
        });
    }
```

`photo.entity.ts`

```
@Entity()
export class Photo { // No changes here
    //...

    @OneToMany(() => PhotoComment, (photoComment: PhotoComment) => photoComment.photo)
    public photoComments: PhotoComment[];

    @OneToMany(() => PhotoRating, (photoRating: PhotoRating) => photoRating.photo)
    public photoRatings: PhotoRating[];
}
```

`photo-comment.entity.ts`

```
@Entity()
export class PhotoComment { // Deleted JoinColumn because I don't need that
    //...

    @ManyToOne(() => Photo, (photo: Photo) => photo.photoComments, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    public photo: Photo;

    @ManyToOne(() => PhotoRating, (photoRating: PhotoRating) => photoRating.photoComment)
    public photoRating: PhotoRating;
}
```

`photo-rating.entity.ts`

```
@Entity()
@Unique(['user', 'photo'])
export class PhotoRating { // Deleted { cascade: true | from PhotoComment because I don't want it
    //...
    
    @Transform(({ value }) => +value)
    @Column({ type: 'decimal', precision: 3, scale: 2, default: 0 })
    public rate: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => Photo, (photo: Photo) => photo.photoRatings, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    public photo: Photo;

    @OneToMany(() => PhotoComment, (photoComment: PhotoComment) => photoComment.photoRating)
    public photoComment: PhotoComment;
}
```

And now it's working perfectly and fast. I had also to adjust my code when user adds a comment when photo is already rated but that's the same case with `.update()` method like above

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the problem is that you have not set the *photoComment*

property on the photoRating entity. To do this, add the following code to the *ratePhoto method*

```
photoRating.photoComment = photoComment;
```

This will ensure that the *photoComment* property of the *photoRating* entity is set correctly.

**The method should be as follows**

```
public ratePhoto(photoId: number, ratePhotoDto: RatePhotoDto, user: User): Observable<any> {
  return this.getPhoto(photoId).pipe(
    switchMap((photo: Photo) => from(this.photoRatingRepository.findOneBy({ photo: { id: photo.id }, user: { id: user.id } })).pipe(
      map((photoRating: PhotoRating) => {
        if (!photoRating) {
          const newRating: PhotoRating = new PhotoRating();
          newRating.rate = ratePhotoDto.rate;
          newRating.user = user;
          newRating.photo = photo;
          return this.photoRatingRepository.save(newRating);
        }
        photoRating.rate = ratePhotoDto.rate;
        photoRating.photoComment = photoComment;
        return this.photoRatingRepository.save(photoRating);
      }),
    )),
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't have a `photoComment` data here. I need that rate to be visible for all comments of specific user so, maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think that getting all these comments here and manually setting rate to them every time user changes rate is a good approach

Comment: There are some indications that you may have used an AI tool (e.g., ChatGPT) to assist with this answer.  If so, I'd encourage you to delete it since [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow].